# Wireless Ear Buds With Multipoint, ANC, and Mono Pod Usage

Tags: bluetooth, headphones, earphones

I have searched high and low for a set of ear pods that check all my boxes.

Let's say cost is not an issue, cheap or expensive, either works. They need to be true wireless earbuds, no over ear or buds connected by a wire.

**I need a pair of earbuds with the following features (at a minimum).**

- Active Noise Cancellation
- Bluetooth Multipoint
- Ability to use each "bud" in mono mode

I almost purchased the Jabra Elite 85t, but you can only use the one "bud" in mono mode, which was a deal breaker.

Does anyone have a hardware recommendation for me here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up buying the Huawei Freebuds Pro, which seem to check all the boxes.

Edit: can confirm, they check all these boxes. Good purchase.

Comment: When using multipoint, are you able to listen to multiple devices at once? Or is it just connected to two devices at once, and you can only listen to one at a time?